# Java: Reading images/files inside the compiled .jar throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java

I have a class that compiles a bunch of textures from a given folder into one big BufferedImage. It works perfectly when I run my program inside the IDE (Eclipse), but when I export it to a .jar, it throws a NullPointerException because it's not able to see the files inside the jar.

I think this has something to do with the `File` class, but I'm not sure.

The class's constructor takes a String `path` which represents the path to a folder inside the project's src folder. I use this line here to turn the partial path into a full path:

```
path = getFullPath(path);
```

The `getFullPath` method is just one line:

```
public String getFullPath(String path)
{
    return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(path).getPath();
}
```

I then iterate through all files in the folder at `path`:

```
for(File f : new File(path).listFiles())
```

This works flawlessly in the IDE. For example, when I pass `assets/textures/sky/` into the constructor as `path`, it successfully finds `/C:/Users/MyName/eclipse-workspace/ProjectName/bin/assets/textures/sky/`, then iterates through all the files in that folder.

However, when I export the project as a .jar and run it, it throws a `NullPointerException` when it gets to `new File(path).lisFiles()` because it can't find anything there. I've printed `path` to the console and the path is correct save for an `!`exclamation mark after the name of the .jar, which makes me think that the File class can't read .jars.

I'm aware of classes like ZipFile or JarFile that work differently, but I'm not familiar with them, and Google has not been helpful. Would anyone like to lend me a hand with this?

Comment: Don't use `File` to read/process resources. Resources are not files. As far as I know, there's no clean way to list resources under a package via the resource API.

Comment: Ah, that's annoying. Thank you.